# Do not displaying first chart point chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs lib to draw charts.
And I want to draw some simple, linear chart, but when do it some how the first point of the chart isn't shown correctly :

https://scr.hu/ALkPXP

It happends when the lowest data point x value have the same value as the minimum xAxes.

When I decrease minimum ax value it works correcty:

https://scr.hu/Gw4Lpy

My whole chart looks like :

```
const scatterChart2 = new Chart(this.canvas.nativeElement,
      {
      'type': 'line',
      'data':
        {
          'datasets': [
            {
              'label': 'Scatter Dataset',
              'data': [
                {
                  x: 1,
                  y: 0,
                }, {
                x: 65,
                y: 20,
              }, {
                x: 30,
                y: 22,
              }, {
                x: 44,
                y: 55,
              }],
              'fill': false,
              'borderColor': 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'
            }]
        },
        'options': {
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                min: 1,
                stepSize: 1
              },
              offset: true,
              type: 'linear',
              position: 'bottom'
            }]
          },
          'showLines': true
        }
      });

  }
```

And in HTML my Canvas looks like :

```
<div style="max-width: 1000px;max-height: 1000px;">
  <canvas #canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

How should I show first point correctly ?